# Better way of finding $\int {x^2 + 1 \over x^4 + x^2 + 1} dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int {x^2 +  1 \over x^4 + x^2 + 1} dx$$

---

By separating partial fractions,

$${Ax + B \over x^2 - x + 1}  + {Cx + D \over x^2 + x + 1}  = {x^2 + 1 \over x^4 + x^2 + 1} \\ \implies (Ax + B)(x^2 + x + 1) + (Cx + D)(x^2 - x + 1) = x^2 + 1$$

I get $$\begin{cases} A = -1/2 \\ 
 B = 1/2\\
 C = 1/2 \\
D = 1/2\end{cases}$$

For which the integrand becomes

$${1 \over 2}\int {1 - x\over x^2 - x + 1} dx + {1\over2} \int {x + 1\over x^2 + x + 1} dx$$

Now these two are easy enough to solve but still very tedious, not to mention that partial fractions was also very tedious.

Is there a  less cumbersome way to solve this ? I tried to change the integrand of form $1 + 1/x^2$ so that I substitute $u = 1 - 1/x$ but was unsuccessful .

Comment: Try completing the square

Comment: If you are interested in the primitive, my feeling is that there is no way for avoiding a partial fraction decomposition. However, some values of the integral over particular ranges (like $(0,1)$) can be tackled without resorting to that.

Comment: The form of the primitive, given by a combination of $\arctan\frac{2x\pm 1}{\sqrt{3}}$, suggests that to exploit the points $x=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ for symmetry might lead to some simplification.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How can I exploit $x = \pm 1/2$ for symmetry ?

Comment: @A---B: $\frac{1-x}{x^2-x+1}$ simplifies a lot by setting $x=2z+1$, for instance.

Comment: You may also notice that the poles of $\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2+x^4}=\frac{1-x^4}{1-x^6}$ have a nice configuration - some sixth roots of unity differs exactly by one.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But for that I need to use partial fraction first on the original rational function right ?

Comment: @A---B: yes, or something similar depending on the previous geometric argument.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I want to avoid Partial fraction as much as possible, this was a olympiad question, so I guess there has to be a quick way.

Comment: If it would have been $(1+x^2)/(1-x^2+x^4)$ a primitive would have been $\arctan(x-1/x)$. Was this really an olympiad question? Do you have a link? I did not think they used analysis in the olympiads...

Comment: @mickep No I don't have any link, my friend send me a picture of the question paper sheet.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How can use geometric argument in integration ? I would like to know.

Comment: Hey it should be $A=C=0$ and $B=D=1/2$,[WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2B1)%2F(x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1)+partial+fraction)

Comment: @A---B: by decomposing $\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2+x^4}=g(x^2)$ as $f(x)+f(-x)$, with $f(x)$ having its poles at $e^{\pm i/3}$.

Comment: @kingW3 That is the sole reason I want to avoid PFD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note
$$ \int {x^2 +  1 \over x^4 + x^2 + 1} dx=\int {1+\frac1{x^2} \over x^2 + \frac1{x^2} + 1} dx=\int\frac{1}{(x-\frac1x)^2+3}d(x-\frac1x).$$
Now letting $u=x-\frac1x$, you can easily solve the problem

Comment: Clever, and awesome. Thank you very much.

Comment: I mark the answer afterward, it is very late now. sorry.

Comment: @A---B, you are welcome.

Comment: Oh, I thought I played with the constants in $\arctan(a x+b/x)$ to conclude that this was not possible (see my comment to the question). Nice!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a funny way that I noticed by chance. I don't see really why it would work, it popped out when I played with the function. In any case, I think someone might get something out of it, so I post it.

We first notice that
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2+x^4}-\frac{a}{b+x^2}=\frac{b-a+(1+b-a)x^2+(1-a)x^4}{b+(1+b)x^2+(1+b)x^4+x^6}
$$
If we choose $b=3$ then the denominator becomes
$$
3+(2x+x^3)^2,
$$
and the right-hand side becomes
$$
\frac{3-a+(4-a)x^2+(1-a)x^4}{3+(2x+x^3)^2}
$$
If we next choose $a=1$ the numerator magically becomes the derivative of $2x+x^3$!

Thus, we conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2+x^4}\,dx
&=\int\Bigl(\frac{1}{3+x^2}+\frac{2+3x^2}{3+(2x+x^3)^2}\Bigr)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigl(\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}+\arctan\frac{2x+x^3}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigr)+C.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is a very smart observation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to perform the awkward substitution $x=\frac{-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3+4t^2}}{2t}$ to simply get $\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{3}(1+t^2)}$, but of course this approach just follows from reverse-engineering the straightforward solution through partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you plug $x=i$ into $$(Ax+B)(x^2+x+1)+(Cx+D)(x^2-x+1)=x^2+1$$
You get $$Bi-A+C-Di=(C-A)+(B-D)i=0$$
or $C=A,B=D$ so
$$(Ax+B)(x^2+x+1+x^2-x+1)=2(Ax+B)(x^2+1)=x^2+1$$
From this it's easy to see that $A=C=0$ and $B=D=1/2$

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when doing PFD next time :).